# Cloud function not executing ref.once on realtime db

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

My cloud function was working fine this morning. But now it suddenly stopped working. So I added a few more logs and I noticed that `rootRef.once` was not executing. Why could this be happening? The function keeps on timing out.

```
exports.assignTeams = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const judgeId = data.judgeId;
  console.log("Assigning teams to judge ", judgeId);
  var db = admin.database();
  var rootRef = db.ref("/");
  rootRef.once(
    "value",
    function(snapshot) {
      console.log("Passed value ", snapshot);
      processAssignedQueue(snapshot, judgeId);
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log("ERROR:\n" + error);
      return { teams: [] };
    }
  );
});
```

The console logs from Firebase:

[image: firebase console]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're not returning a promise from the function that resolves with the data to send to the caller.  Right now, your function is actually returning nothing, because `once()` is asynchronous and returns immediately before the query is complete.  When a callable function returns without a promise, it shuts down immediately, an any asynchronous work will not complete.

Also, you should note that the return statements inside the callbacks you passed to once() are only return values from those individual function callbacks, not the entire function.

What you should do instead is make use of the promise returned by `once()`, and use that to determine what to return to the client.  Here's a simple example:

```
return rootRef.once("value")
.then(snapshot => {
    console.log("Passed value ", snapshot);
    return { data: snapshot.val() }
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log("ERROR:\n" + error);
  return { teams: [] };
});
```

In order to write Cloud Functions effectively, you will need to **fully** understand how javascript promises work.  If you don't work with them correctly, your functions will fail in mysterious ways.

Comment: So my function works 90% of the time. There is this edge case where I noticed it fails. But regardless of that, should I call the function `processAssignedQueue(snapshot, judgeId);` in the `then` part?

Comment: Sure, and if it does more asynchronous work, you will need to handle those promises as well. You cannot ignore any promises, as that work might not survive if the function terminates before they are complete.  The final promise you return from the function should only resolve after **all** other promises have resolved.

Comment: But in the syntax I used, don't the functions in arguments of once after "value":  i.e. fn1, fn2 act as a promise and error function? I thought this was a different style of writing the same thing?

Comment: Also in `judgingQueueRef.set(judgingQueue);` how would I handle the promise and wait for the setting to be completed before returning?

Comment: No, the callback you used don't act like promises at all.  They are just async callbacks and don't do anything with promises.

Comment: If you have another question, please post it separately.

Comment: Turns out that this is not the reason why my function was timing out. But thanks for the tip. Helped clean up some other things for me.

Comment: If you don't mind, an upvote is appropriate for answers that were helpful.